# How does htop calculate times? (Impossible times shown)

Tags: cpu, timestamps, top, cluster, htop

I was running what was supposed to be a small make job on a small node in our cluster, but a sorting process seemed to be overwhelming the allocated RAM, so I killed it after 20 hours (same jobs on other samples finished in 4-5 hours). I then deleted the output files and re-ran the job on a node with much more RAM. htop showed that a few processes, after 1 hour on the new node, had been running 20 to 55 hours. How does htop calculate the displayed cumulative time running? Why in the world would it think that something that had been running 1 hour had been there for 55 hours?

I'm certain the processes were related to this specific job based on the files called.

Comment: How many CPUs on the node in question?

Comment: The original node had 4 and the second one has 14, but I only grabbed 6 of them.

Comment: 10 threads on each of the six CPUs could give you 50+ hours of time in one wall-clock hour, I suppose.